# Invalid Button ID

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using Oracle Application Express 5.1.

In my apex application some Page Processes, Branches or Valdiations lost the "When Button Pressed" linking.
The buttons work so far.

But if the application is exported and imported again, the buttons do not work anymore. (In the export file, the non-existent Button-ID is referenced)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the button item exist in the export file with a different ID? If so, you could do a find-replace in the file to fix it. But this sounds like a bug, I would report it to Oracle Support.

Comment: Yes. That way I could fix it. But the problem has occurred again.

Comment: When you do an export, under 'Export Preferences', try exporting with 'Export with Original IDs' set to 'Yes'.

Answer (score 0):

This happens also when duplicating pages. the solution is to search for references of the old button ID, and manually replace it with the right select list item of the  button.

as I understand it, apex gives a randInt ID to each button that doesn't have a specified "static ID", so if this really bugs you it is possible to define the button click as a dynamic action on the jQuery selector defined by the static ID of the button.

Hopefully they will fix the problem by Apex 18.3, cause this also happened with Apex 18.2